# mat date picker selected date is not matching

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

The selected date from the mat date picker and its value in the reactive form is not matching.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.findForm = this._fb.group({
      date: ['', Validators.required]
    });
}
```

And in the template,

```
<mat-form-field [formGroup]="findForm">
  <input matInput formControlName="date" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

<pre>{{this.findForm.get('date').value |json }}</pre>
```

I have the full working [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-datepicker-format-whqkpv?file=app%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.html) on stackblitz

Select a date and you see the selected date and its value in the reactive form is not same.

Comment: It's picking the UTC date, and displaying the local date after any time difference

Comment: @user184994 so how do I handle this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [day incorrect in angular material datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48710053/day-incorrect-in-angular-material-datepicker)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, Dates from the MatDatePicker are in UTC format. But you can convert those into the local format using this:

```
formatDate() {
  var date = new Date(`${this.findForm.value.date} UTC`);
  return date.toString();
}
```

And in template:

```
<mat-form-field [formGroup]="findForm">
  <input matInput formControlName="date" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

<pre>{{ formatDate() }}</pre>
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-datepicker-format-eg) for your ref.

Comment: @anonymous, doesn't work as in? Doesn't work the way you want it to be? Or doesn't open/work in general?

Comment: The date is null.

Comment: Initially, it is null and so it shows Invalid Date. But then when you select a date, it shows the correct date.