# How to change the date format while saving in material date picker?

Tags: angular-material, angular-material-datetimepicker, angular-date-format

I wanted to save the date from material date picker. But while saving my date the saved date is one day behind.

**Input date:**

[image]

**Saved date:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Angular material date picker does not support different time zones and it gives you an UTC time offset. You have to modify the javascript code.

You can take a look here:
[day incorrect in angular material datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48710053/day-incorrect-in-angular-material-datepicker)