# Why can't I provide config at (standalone) component level?

Tags: angular, momentjs, angular-providers, angular-standalone-components

I'm working with Angular Material and moment.js. I had the problem that dates were parsed according to my timezone, instead of just, well, what the user entered.

There's already a question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48710053/day-incorrect-in-angular-material-datepicker) and it also has a working [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57036583/8447743). But it's rather old, not taking into account standalone components, which do offer the possibility of providing stuff directly at the component level. However, that does not work in this case:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-with-material-datepicker',
  templateUrl: './component-with-material-datepicker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component-with-material-datepicker.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatMomentDateModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: ErrorStateMatcher, useClass: InstantErrorStateMatcher }, // works
    MomentDateAdapter,
    { provide: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, useValue: { useUtc: true } }, // no effect
  ],
})
export class ComponentWithMaterialDatePicker {
 // ...
```

This leaves me no choice but to provide the config at module level. I wish to understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But that provider is an [`environmentProvider`](https://angular.io/api/core/EnvironmentProviders) and they need to be placed in the providers array of `bootstrapApplication` second parameter. So could you check the below stackblitz. Where I add in environment providers and it seems to work fine!

Important points:

- We need to use a separate package.

import

```
import { provideMomentDateAdapter } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
```

- We need to add this provider code in the bootstrap application section as shown below.

code

```
bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    importProvidersFrom(MatNativeDateModule),
    provideMomentDateAdapter(undefined, { useUtc: true }),
    provideAnimations(),
  ],
});
```

code

```
import { Component, importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { FormControl, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import moment from 'moment';
import { MatNativeDateModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { provideMomentDateAdapter } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CommonModule,
  ],
  template: `
    <mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Moment.js datepicker</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp" [formControl]="date">
  <mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="dp"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #dp></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

{{date.value | json}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  date = new FormControl(moment([2017, 0, 1]));
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    importProvidersFrom(MatNativeDateModule),
    provideMomentDateAdapter(undefined, { useUtc: true }),
    provideAnimations(),
  ],
});
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fh8sjz?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fglobal_styles.css&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: I wasn't aware that providers are subdivided into different categories. That answers my question, thx. However, the line `import { provideMomentDateAdapter } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';` does not seem to work anymore (this function is not exported)

Comment: @NoBullsh1t it's actually from the documentation and i provided a working. Example for you, could you recheck